# ffmpeg broken pipeline error when push stream to rtmp server

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I was trying to push stream to a rtmp server. firstly, I use OBS with default settings, it works ok. then I decide to use ffmpeg to do it. below is the command I use.

```
./ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp4 \
 -vcodec libx264 \
 -r 60 \
 -b:v 10000k\
 -vf scale=1920*1080\
 -c:a aac\
 -b:a 160k -ar 48000 -ac 2\
 -f flv\
 -flvflags no_duration_filesize\
 -chunk_size 4096\
 rtmp://txy2.live-push.bilivideo.com/live-bvc/?streamname=live_423756438_27609488&key=***************&schedule=rtmp&pflag=1
  #rtmp://192.168.3.2:1935/live/test
```

all the options above refer from the network packages catched by wireshark when push video with OBS as the screenshot shows below

[image]

but I got some error after the command executed.

[image]

I've tried pushing stream to both of the rtmp server(you can see at the end of the command,one is a vedio website and another is local) with OBS and both works well but neither of them works with the same error message thrown as shown in the first image.